# How to calculate the difference between two cumsum columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
         duid start_date   end_date
0   b2919f1eb 2019-08-26 2019-09-05
1   e372dedd4 2019-08-26        NaT
2   ba8147ce9 2019-09-09 2019-11-05
3   902c56036 2019-09-13 2019-10-01
4   16ec096a7 2019-09-17 2019-10-02
5   1faac1a15 2019-09-17        NaT
6   319fb59f5 2019-09-24 2020-01-20
7   2a3f1dac5 2019-10-01        NaT
8   aecbcf0c5 2019-10-01 2019-11-05
9   0ee088b63 2019-10-08 2019-10-03
10  c0c02fa4c 2019-10-31 2019-10-31
12  aac5fbc7d 2019-11-05 2019-11-05
11  c76bc248a 2019-11-05 2019-11-29
13  20dcef410 2019-11-12        NaT
14  bc7ea631d 2019-11-12        NaT
15  786af275b 2019-11-12 2019-11-12
16  005ec00c8 2019-11-15        NaT
17  482462695 2019-11-19        NaT
18  ecba54e5d 2019-11-26        NaT
19  28490c52f 2019-12-17        NaT
20  02f2f7f4b 2020-01-15        NaT
21  0ea659d1a 2020-01-29        NaT
22  0b78caca1 2020-01-29        NaT
23  368cc8744 2020-01-29 2020-01-29
```

This table describes staff hired and left dates.  So far I've managed to calculate the count per month:

```py
df.groupby(df['start_date'].dt.strftime('%Y %B')) \
   .agg(hired=('start_date', 'size'), left=('end_date', 'count')) \
   .reset_index()
```

```
       start_date  hired  left
0     2019 August      2     1
1   2019 December      1     0
2   2019 November      8     3
3    2019 October      4     3
4  2019 September      5     4
5    2020 January      4     1
```

Also, I've tried to calculate the cumulative sum of each date, but it returns weird results

```py
ds = df.groupby(df['start_date'].dt.strftime('%Y %B'))
ds.size().cumsum()
```

```
start_date
2019 August        2
2019 December      3
2019 November     11
2019 October      15
2019 September    20
2020 January      24
dtype: int64
```

And the cumulative lefts...

```py
de = df.groupby(df['end_date'].dt.strftime('%Y %B'))
de.size().cumsum()
```

```
end_date
2019 November      5
2019 October       9
2019 September    10
2020 January      12
dtype: int64
```

There's a sort thing, I don't know why the table doesn't take the sort order by `start_date`, but that issue is not as relevant as to calculate the difference between the two values i.e.:

```
df = df.sort_values('start_date')
```

How can I sum the cumulative of two columns, `start_date` and `end_date` to get the following result

```
       start_date  hired  left  rooster
0     2019 August      2     1        1
1  2019 September      5     4        2
2    2019 October      4     3        3
3   2019 November      8     3        8
4   2019 December      1     0        9
5    2020 January      4     1       12
```

Comment: The table does not sort by date because your date are string, not `datetime`. You should consider replacing `dt.strftime('%Y %B')` by `dt.to_period('M')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably find it easier to leave the grouping key as a datetime like object and then just reformat it at the end so sorting works correctly. (So pd.Grouper with a freq or .to_period(...) etc...)

Start with getting your initial aggregate figures and sort by the grouped index so your data is guaranteed to be in sorted order:

```
agg = (
    df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='start_date', freq='M'))['end_date']
    .agg(hired='size', left='count')
    .sort_index()
)
```

Then assign a new column for the running total of the roster...

```
agg['roster'] = agg['hired'].cumsum() - agg['left'].cumsum()
```

Then reformat your index and reset it, eg:

```
agg = agg.set_index(agg.index.strftime('%Y %B')).reset_index()
```

Will give you:

```
       start_date  hired  left  roster
0     2019 August      2     1       1
1  2019 September      5     4       2
2    2019 October      4     3       3
3   2019 November      8     3       8
4   2019 December      1     0       9
5    2020 January      4     1      12
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I'm looking for, in combination with @Quang_Hoang input regarding date transformation.  This is magic to me. Thanks!